# Test Red Line Coverage PHPUnit

Tags: mocking, phpunit, phpstorm, code-coverage

I writing test for PHP Trait class. When i run test with coverage on PhpStorm IDE it show some red line on editor line number and give me the result 76% on coverage test lines like this

[image]

My question is how to test on that lines so it will give me the result 100% lines

Here is my test code :

Response.php

```
<?php

trait Response {
    /**
     * Failed to login response.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function failedLogin(): array
    {
        return [
            'code'    => 401,
            'message' => 'Failed to login',
        ];
    }   
}
```

ResponseTest.php

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ResponseTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var MockObject|Response|null
     */
    private ?MockObject $mock;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->mock = $this->getMockForTrait(Response::class);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_correct_output_failed_login()
    {
        $response = $this->mock->failedLogin();

        $this->assertResponse($response, 401, 'Failed to login');
    }
    
    /**
     * Assert response.
     *
     * @param  array  $response
     * @param  int  $code
     * @param  null  $message
     */
    private function assertResponse(array $response, $code = 200, $message = null)
    {
        $this->assertIsArray($response);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('code', $response);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('message', $response);
        $this->assertContains($code, $response);
        $this->assertContains($message, $response);
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        $this->mock = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce that](https://prnt.sc/xnic0m) in PhpStorm 2020.3.1 with PHPUnit 9.3.8. Do you think you could share the entire project including the `.idea` folder rather these two files?

Comment: i dont know why when i try it again the red line dissapear.. Thanks

Comment: for me this happens when clicking `add to active suites`
first time I get 100%, the moment I click on other test to be added, the initial test gets retested and drops to 70%